# Can't get DLNA media server to appear on Xbox One from Ubuntu Server

Tags: server, dlna, minidlna

So I recently installed a home server to practice remote access, media file share etc...
Currently SSH or Samba service work perfectly through out all devices in the network, however I wish to view a specific folder from my xbox using the Media Player app.

I set up the minidlna.conf file to what I presume is the correct settings since the recent experience I had with setting up samba. Restart service, force-reload, verified status and it shows as active.

**Nothing, nada.**

I'm no expert obviously but I believe it has to do with the port in the .conf file but I just have no idea which port should be there. Should I open I new port in my router? How secure is it to open ports from my modem?

Here is my minidlna.conf:

```
# If you want to restrict a media_dir to a specific content type, you can
# prepend the directory name with a letter representing the type (A, P or V),
# followed by a comma, as so:
#   * "A" for audio    (eg. media_dir=A,/var/lib/minidlna/music)
#   * "P" for pictures (eg. media_dir=P,/var/lib/minidlna/pictures)
#   * "V" for video    (eg. media_dir=V,/var/lib/minidlna/videos)
#   * "PV" for pictures and video (eg. media_dir=PV,/var/lib/minidlna/digital_camera)
media_dir=V,/home/obama420
media_dir=v,/srv/HomeNetwork/DefetnetlynotPORN/Videos


# Set this to merge all media_dir base contents into the root container
# (The default is no.)
#merge_media_dirs=no

# Path to the directory that should hold the database and album art cache.
db_dir=/var/cache/minidlna

# Path to the directory that should hold the log file.
log_dir=/var/log

 Network interface(s) to bind to (e.g. eth0), comma delimited.
# This option can be specified more than once.
#network_interface=enp0s25

# Port number for HTTP traffic (descriptions, SOAP, media transfer).
# This option is mandatory (or it must be specified on the command-line using
# "-p").
port=3074

# URL presented to clients (e.g. http://example.com:80).
#presentation_url=/

# Name that the DLNA server presents to clients.
# Defaults to "hostname: username".
friendly_name=Home_Server
```

I'm not sure what other info I could provide to make it easier for anyone to assist me with this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change `media_dir=v,/srv/HomeNetwork/DefetnetlynotPORN/Videos` to `media_dir=V,/srv/HomeNetwork/DefetnetlynotPORN/Videos`.

Comment: Didnt make it work. Would it have anything to do that the files are in different video formats?

Comment: What's your video format?